# How to configure my SBS 2008 server to support Co-authoring of Word documents

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs

My organization is using a **SBS 2008** server for managing our file-system. As far as I understand it comes with **SharePoint** installed on it, although it is currently not in use.

We have got **office 2010** and I realized that this office version contains a very significant feature for our work - [Co authoring](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgI4OlZTOzM) of Word documents- i.e. being able to edit the same word files simultaneously.

However our IT guys currently refuses to reconfigure our server in order to enable this feature, saying that this is complicated need SharePoint expertise and requires long time.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to enable it on our Business Server?
2. Will it require days to configure the server to support it, if our SBS
   is currently using the default configuration?

This question is also published in a [Professional Microsoft forum for this subject](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/273b2460-bb6c-4dea-abcb-c6cfd6380f90).

---

Comment: Yes and Yes; both depending on a bunch of information we don't have.  But this is off-topic for SU, as we are here for questions and answers that are practical and not rhetorical or 'opinion'-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2010 and Office 2010 has document co-authoring automatically enabled. There is nothing that you need to do except use the DOCX format and Office 2010 apps when workign with the document.